# Natural gas fireplace valve replacement?

Tags: plumbing, fireplace

I had my natural gas fireplace inspected and the technician said that the valve is faulty and needs replacement, and that they could do the job for $1700, as there are four parts that need replacing. Does this seem reasonable? I am a bit confused about how, if the valve is faulty, the pilot light can light without a problem, and continue burning while the pilot ignitor is held down without a problem. I'm no expert but it seems wrong. It seems more like a control unit problem. And I do realize the valve is turned off, thanks!

[image: fireplace valve]

Comment: when they say "the valve" what do they mean?  Replacing the shutoff in the photo is a no-brainer effort.  Replacing the pilot/lighter/controller isn't much harder.  The thing that would be hard is replacing the shutoff that's often bricked in on your hearth. That said, it isn't hard to spend $800 on all the parts, and if that's the case then doubling to install is probably around correct.

Comment: Can get other opinions/inspections.  Do not need to go with the first one.  It is something I would not want to guess about due to great potential of dying.

Comment: If you are even moderately proficient with tools and mechanical appliances you might want to post a new question providing the specific issues/symptoms (with pictures) you're having with your gas fireplace. There are experts here on SE who might be able to help you diagnose the problem and offer a recommended solution. Even if you hire a technician, in the end you'll be in a much stronger position to understand what needs to be done.

Comment: Pricing is off-topic, yadda, yadda... but a second opinion seems wise if the cost seems absurdly high. Which it does. That's a substantial part of "whole new fireplace" and that might be worth considering if the figure holds up.

Comment: Check out how much a whole set of nice gas logs and compare it to the quotes you get for parts replacement.